# Best Practice for Adding .gitignore to Repo

Tags: git, gitignore

What is the best practice regarding the *.gitignore* file with Git; should it be excluded from the repository or included? If it's conditional, what are the conditions for each circumstance?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

They should almost always be included, as their purpose is to ignore "output" files (compiled binaries, log files) which are going to be generated by anybody working with a clone of your project. They're meant to be version-controlled and included with the repository.

You should not use `.gitignore` files within the repository to ignore files that only appear for you, such as editor-specific swap files. You should be placing those rules in a [global `.gitignore` file](http://help.github.com/ignore-files/) so that they apply to all repositories, or in `.git/info/excludes`.